# preact-cli/babel/typescript - getting Symbol.iterator and [...spread] to work correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, preact

In my code, I have a function called `range` that produces ranges. The implementation is as follows:

```ts
export const range = (min: number, max: number) => {
    // ...

    return {
        // ...
        *[Symbol.iterator]() {
            let n = min

            while (n <= max) yield n++
        }
    }
}
```

`Array.from(range(1, 5))` gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, as you'd expect. However, `[...range(1, 5)]` gives `[{[Symbol.iterator]: ƒ}]` (array of length 1, containing the range object), which is clearly not correct. If I attach `range` to the `window` object and call it from the browser console, `[...range(1, 5)]` gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, as expected.

Upon further debugging, it seems the spread operator is being transpiled to this:

```
// console.log(() => [...range(1, 5)])
ƒ () { return [].concat(range(1, 5)) }
```

This would work OK if what was being spread was an array, but fails for other types of iterables.

`.tsconfig` is identical to ones I've used before, targeting `ESNext`, and changing `downlevelIteration` to either `true` or `false` does nothing, so I'm fairly confident the problem isn't there.

It looks like this is something to do with Babel, but I can't work out how to configure it correctly. Legacy browser support isn't much of a concern - if it's working on latest Chromium and Firefox, I'm happy.

`package.json`:

```
"browserslist": "last 3 chrome versions, last 3 firefox versions"
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{ "presets": [ [ "preact-cli/babel", { "modules": "commonjs" } ] ] }
```

`preact.config.js` is identical to the one here: [`preact.config.js` permalink](https://github.com/preactjs-templates/widget-typescript/blob/8551c0c/template/preact.config.js). Here's the relevant part:

```
webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
    // ...

    config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
        if (rule.loader === 'babel-loader') {
            const use = [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: rule.options
                },
                {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            ]

            return {
                ...rule,
                loader: undefined,
                options: undefined,
                use,
            }
        }
        // ...    
    })
    // ...
}
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: `"downlevelIteration": true` seems to solve the problem on my side: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-bush-ns3y7?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt That app uses Parcel, not Webpack, Babel, and Preact. The problem is definitely in the build tooling, not the code.

Comment: @Yeah, you're right. I looked up a little bit and found [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-spread#allowarraylike). Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

I will just repeat solution provided by @PeterLehnhardt in comments, so everybody can see it:
Create preact.config.js

```
export default {
  webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
    const { rule } = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'babel-loader')[0];
    const babelConfig = rule.options;

    babelConfig.assumptions = {
      iterableIsArray: false, 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally fixed this by simply removing `babel-loader` altogether. I replaced the relevant part of `preact.config.js` with this:

```
if (rule.loader === 'babel-loader') {
    return { loader: 'ts-loader' }
}
```

I'd still be curious to see answers for how to fix this *without* removing Babel entirely, though.

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt indicated the necessary configuration in his comment. This is not really an answer but an unnecessary work around.

Comment: My question was "how can I fix this", self-answer because it fixed my problem and fits my use case (modern browsers only) perfectly. I don't consider this a workaround, because I didn't need Babel in the first place. Also I posted this before @PeterLehnhard's second comment (which is probably better as a general solution, even if not for my specific case).